# Voice Recognition in PowerPoint using VBA Macros

Tags: vba, powerpoint, voice-recognition

A week ago I had a presentation where I was making an AI using Voice Recognition with VBA. It worked perfectly (I took the code from [this WebSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) till some day I was going to test it again and it didn't work. It returns an error

> "Run-time error '70': Permission denied"

I checked my microphone and the VBA References needed that are mentioned in the WebSite. Then I went to the Site I took the code from and I saw a different version of the code (Public, Shared...) and when I ran it, another error appears

> "Run-time error '-2147200905 (80045077)': Automation error"

So can someone please help me, the code used to work and I didn't change anything. Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents RC As SpInProcRecoContext
Dim Recognizer As SpInprocRecognizer
Dim myGrammar As ISpeechRecoGrammar

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'On Error GoTo EH

    Set RC = New SpInProcRecoContext
    Set Recognizer = RC.Recognizer

    Set myGrammar = RC.CreateGrammar
    myGrammar.DictationSetState SGDSActive

    Dim Category As SpObjectTokenCategory
    Set Category = New SpObjectTokenCategory
    Category.SetId SpeechCategoryAudioIn

    Dim Token As SpObjectToken
    Set Token = New SpObjectToken
    Token.SetId Category.Default()
    Set Recognizer.AudioInput = Token

'EH:
'    If Err.Number Then ShowErrMsg
End Sub




Private Sub RC_Recognition(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant, ByVal RecognitionType As SpeechLib.SpeechRecognitionType, ByVal Result As SpeechLib.ISpeechRecoResult)
    On Error GoTo EH

    TextBox1.text = Result.PhraseInfo.GetText


EH:
    If Err.Number Then ShowErrMsg
End Sub


Private Sub ShowErrMsg()

    ' Declare identifiers:
    Const NL = vbNewLine
    Dim T As String

    T = "Desc: " & Err.Description & NL
    T = T & "Err #: " & Err.Number
    MsgBox T, vbExclamation, "Run-Time Error"
    'End

End Sub


'### Second version of the code (Shared, Public...)

        Option Explicit

    Public WithEvents RC As SpSharedRecoContext
    Public myGrammar As ISpeechRecoGrammar

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        'On Error GoTo EH

        Set RC = New SpSharedRecoContext

        Set myGrammar = RC.CreateGrammar
        myGrammar.DictationSetState SGDSActive

    'EH:
        'If Err.Number Then ShowErrMsg
    End Sub

    Private Sub RC_Recognition(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant, ByVal RecognitionType As SpeechLib.SpeechRecognitionType, ByVal Result As SpeechLib.ISpeechRecoResult)
        Label1.Caption = Result.PhraseInfo.GetText
    End Sub

    Private Sub RC_StartStream(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant)
        'Label2.Caption = Val(StreamNumber)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowErrMsg()

        ' Declare identifiers:
        Const NL = vbNewLine
        Dim T As String

        T = "Desc: " & Err.Description & NL
        T = T & "Err #: " & Err.Number
        MsgBox T, vbExclamation, "Run-Time Error"
        End

    End Sub
```

Comment: Well I adapted it to my needs, but yeah I took it from another WebSite

Comment: It worked before and after a few days it stopped working...

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: This line: 
`Set RC = New SpInProcRecoContext`

Answer (score 1):

That error is saying:

SPERR_RECOGNIZER_NOT_FOUND  0x80045077  -2147200905
No recognizer is installed.

Comment: So what do I do? How do I install the recognizer?